# VB.Net, specify a thread for BackgroundWorker to use?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

This is far-fetched I know but I have to ask. Is there a way to specify the thread that a `BackgroundWorker` instance is to use? Or at least some way to force it onto another specific thread (whose reference I have). I have a large project that makes use of `BackgroundWorker`, and I have just recently started using some in-house FRAMEWORK (I have to) that uses `Thread` instead, and the two seem not be happy with each other (I know the reason but I can not fix it as it is in the framework whose guts I can modify) that is why I ask this question, before I spend days converting my project to use FRAMEWORKS Threading functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to derive from the BackgroundWorker class as it's not sealed and override the methods for RunWorkerAsync etc.  Would be painful and easy to introduce bugs, but that would give you the ability to kick off the DoWork event onto your in house thread framework.

Comment: Good idea, let me look into it